# How can I add on four more circle shapes to my cross figure?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

So far in my code I have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DATA
L = 0.1 #m, length of arm of cross
t = L/2 #m, thickness

# VECTORS OF COORDINATES OF THE CROSS
X = np.array([L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2, t/2, L, L])
Y = np.array([t/2, t/2, L, L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2])

# PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.plot(X,Y,color='C1', linewidth=2.5)
ax.axis('equal')

circle2 = plt.Circle((L - t/2, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circle2)
```

I am looking towards adding four more identical circles to the cross figure, one on each end and one in the center. Can I do this with python?
I attempted to use the same circle 2 code with, different names such as circle3, circle4, etc. and changing the coordinates but it says the name of the circles are not found.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DATA
L = 0.1 #m, length of arm of cross
t = L/2 #m, thickness

# VECTORS OF COORDINATES OF THE CROSS
X = np.array([L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2, t/2, L, L])
Y = np.array([t/2, t/2, L, L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2])

# PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.plot(X,Y,color='C1', linewidth=2.5)
ax.axis('equal')

circle1 = plt.Circle((L - t/2, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circle1)

circle2= plt.Circle((3/2*-t, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circle2)

circle3 = plt.Circle((0,L-t/2), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circle3)

circle4= plt.Circle((0, 3/2*-t), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
ax.add_patch(circle4)
```

[image]

If I got your question right, this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you said was fine, maybe you did something wrong, a typo. Here is the code I tried.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# DATA
L = 0.1 #m, length of arm of cross
t = L/2 #m, thickness

# VECTORS OF COORDINATES OF THE CROSS
X = np.array([L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2, t/2, L, L])
Y = np.array([t/2, t/2, L, L, t/2, t/2, -t/2, -t/2, -L, -L, -t/2, -t/2, t/2])

# PLOT
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,8))
ax.plot(X,Y,color='C1', linewidth=2.5)
ax.axis('equal')

circle2 = plt.Circle((L - t/2, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
circle3 = plt.Circle((-L + t/2, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
circle4 = plt.Circle((0, L-t/2), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
circle5 = plt.Circle((0, -L+t/2), t/4, color='b', fill=False)
circle6 = plt.Circle((0, 0), t/4, color='b', fill=False)

ax.add_patch(circle2)
ax.add_patch(circle3)
ax.add_patch(circle4)
ax.add_patch(circle5)
ax.add_patch(circle6)
plt.show()
```

[image: output]